# How to set alternate url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, socialengine

I have a site  url `www.test.com/profile/david`

Now i need to  access the same page by typing the url `www.test.com/david`

How its possible through .htacccess ?

My existing .htaccess file is as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]


</IfModule>

# sends requests /index.php/path/to/module/ to "index.php"
# AcceptPathInfo On

php_value upload_max_filesize 7M
php_value post_max_size 20M

# @todo This may not be effective in some cases
FileETag Size
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /profile/$1 [L]
```

Comment: ,Thanks for the reply.But its not working.Do i need to restart apache after changing the .htaccess file?

Comment: @anubhava.Please see the question again.I added  my existing .htaccess file

Comment: Sorry to say this but those are some of the strangest looking rules I have ever seen and I can see much of it is not even working. I need to know if `/profile/david` is served by some CMS/PHP framework on your side?